# Methods for finding concavity/convexity of a function

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Is the function $f(x,y)=x+y+2\sqrt{y}$ a concave function or a convex function?

I tried using the Hessian matrix leading principal minors and eigenvalues for finding this. I am getting contradictory results.
Sorry if this seems like a trivial question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with your work - what did you get for Hessian? In what sense are your results contradictory?